# On Upgrade method is called but data not loading

Tags: java, android, database, sqliteopenhelper

I have my first activity (`MainActivity`) having different letters (like A, B, C...). When click on a letter it opens a new activity (`LIstViewActivity`) having a `listView` of words starting with that letter. This list is created from a text file inside `raw` folder and stored in a `database` named suppose `database_a`. In `LIstViewActivity` I am storing a `boolean` in `SharedPreferences`which checks whether `database` of that particular letter is created or not. If it is not created it runs the `initializeDatabase` method otherwise not. These are working fine. But if I increase the `database version` then `onUpgrade` method is called but the `list` is not populating. I also tried to change the `boolean` value inside `onUpgrade` method. In this case on my first attempt data is not populating, when I go back and come again then the data are loading. I think the problem might be due to the `boolean` value. How can I overcome the problem? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks...

This is inside `onCreate` of `ListViewActivity`

```
 //initialize key for the boolean in sharedPreference
    INITIALIZED = "initialized_database_"+class_name;

    //initialize sharedPreference to avoid NullPointerException
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(INITIALIZED, MODE_PRIVATE);

    myDictionaryDatabaseHelper = new DictionaryDatabaseHelper(this, db_name);
    allWordDefinitions = new ArrayList<>();

    initialized = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(INITIALIZED, false);

    //initialize database
    if (!initialized) {

        //initialize database
        initializeDatabase();
    }
    else {
        //Log.e(logTagString, myDictionaryDatabaseHelper.getDatabaseName() +" already initialized.");
    }
```

This is `initializeDatabase` method

```
//initialize the database
private void initializeDatabase() {

    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(db_resource);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        DictionaryLoader.loadData(bufferedReader, myDictionaryDatabaseHelper);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Initializing database...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Log.e(logTagString, "Initializing " + myDictionaryDatabaseHelper.getDatabaseName());

        //change boolean value in sharedPreference editor
        editor.putBoolean(INITIALIZED, true);
        editor.apply();
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Log.e(logTagString, myDictionaryDatabaseHelper.getDatabaseName() +" resource not found!");
        //Log.e(logTagString, myDictionaryDatabaseHelper.getDatabaseName() +" initialization failed!");

        //toast a message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Database resource not found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Database initialization failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //keep the initialized boolean false to reinitialize the database
        editor.putBoolean(INITIALIZED, false);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

This is my `DictionaryDatabaseHelper` class

```
class DictionaryDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_NAME = "db_name";
private final static int DB_VERSION = 2;


private final static String ID_COLUMN = "_id";
private final static String WORD_COLUMN = "word";
private final static String DEFINITION_COLUMN = "definition";

private final String CREATE_DATABASE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "
        +getDatabaseName()+ " ("
        +ID_COLUMN+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        +WORD_COLUMN+ " TEXT, "
        +DEFINITION_COLUMN+ " TEXT)";

private final String UPGRADE_QUERY = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +getDatabaseName();

//constructor to create different named database
DictionaryDatabaseHelper(Context context, String db_name) {
    super(context, db_name, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_QUERY);
    //Log.e("DICTIONARY", "DatabaseHelper onCreate Initializing database...");
    //Log.e("DICTIONARY", "Database name is: " +getDatabaseName());
    //Log.e("DICTIONARY", "Database version is "+db.getVersion());
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //make the database initialization variable false to reinitialize the database
    WordListActivity.editor.putBoolean(WordListActivity.INITIALIZED, false);
    WordListActivity.editor.apply();
    //Log.e("DICTIONARY", "Initialized value is: " +WordListActivity.initialized);



    db.execSQL(UPGRADE_QUERY);
    onCreate(db);

    //Log.e("DICTIONARY", "Upgrading database form version " +oldVersion+ " to " +newVersion);
}

//Initialize database for the first time
void initializeDatabaseForTheFirstTime(ArrayList<WordDefinition> wordDefinitions) {

    //Log.e("DICTIONARY", "Initializing database for the first time.");

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("BEGIN");

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    for (WordDefinition wordDefinition : wordDefinitions) {
        contentValues.put(WORD_COLUMN, wordDefinition.word);
        contentValues.put(DEFINITION_COLUMN, wordDefinition.definition);

        db.insert(getDatabaseName(), null, contentValues);
    }

    db.execSQL("COMMIT");
    db.close();
}
```

}

Comment: I didn't go deep into details but:
1. Looks like in onUpgrade() you are dropping the table, so the database becomes empty.
2. Do not call onCreate() from onUpgrade()
3. Are you going to use a separate database for each letter? If yes, why?

Comment: @Oleh Romanenko, yes, I am creating separate database for each letter. Actually I faced some problem for a single database while making the app. Then I sent each letter id through intent and made a separate database for each letter. The list activity only shows words starting with that letter (I want this). I have as many text files as the letters. I know that sounds crazy. Any suggestion to improve. I don't understand your point no. 2. Please have a look on my helper class, if there is any discrepancy please notify me. Thanks...

Comment: This is your code:
 db.execSQL(UPGRADE_QUERY);
 onCreate(db);

Remove onCreate(db);

You have chosen a very difficult way of how you work with data. Please google how you can use only one database

Comment: If I delete the onCreate() method from `onUpgrade()` method then how will be the deleted table created again? it is also making the app crash as no table is found to insert data.